# Determining max batch size with TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, batchsize

TF Object Detection API grabs all GPU memory by default, so it's difficult to tell how much I can further increase my batch size. Typically I just continue to increase it until I get a CUDA OOM error.

PyTorch on the other hand doesn't grab all GPU memory by default, so it's easy to see what percentage I have left to work with, without all the trial and error.

Is there a better way to determine batch size with the TF Object Detection API that I'm missing? Something like an `allow-growth` flag for `model_main.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking in  the source code and I have found no FLAG related to this.

But, in the file `model_main.py` of https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main.py
you can find the following main function definition:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  flags.mark_flag_as_required('model_dir')
  flags.mark_flag_as_required('pipeline_config_path')
  config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)

  train_and_eval_dict = model_lib.create_estimator_and_inputs(
      run_config=config,
...
```

the idea would be to modify it in a similar way such as the following manner:

```
config_proto = tf.ConfigProto()
config_proto.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, session_config=config_proto)
```

So, adding `config_proto` and changing `config` but maintaining all other things equal.

Also, `allow_growth` makes the program use as much GPU memory as it needs. So, depending on you GPU you might end up with all memory eaten. In this case you may want to use

```
config_proto.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
```

which defines the fraction of memory to use.

Hope this has helped.

If you do not want to modify the file it seems that a issue should be open because I do not see any FLAG. unless the FLAG

```
flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', None, 'Path to pipeline config '
                    'file.')
```

Means something related to this. But I do not think so becuase from what It seems in `model_lib.py` it is related to train, eval and infer configurations not GPU usage configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I think this might be a good workaround. I'll try it out tomorrow morning and report back.