# Sometimes get the error "err == cudaSuccess || err == cudaErrorInvalidValue Unexpected CUDA error: out of memory"

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm very lost on how to solve my particular problem, which is why I followed the getting help guideline in the [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and made a post here on Stack Overflow.

To start off, my goal was to run distributed training jobs on Azure. I've previously used `gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training` with great ease to run distributed jobs, but it's a bit difficult on Azure.

I built the tf1 docker image for the Object Detection API from the dockerfile [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/dockerfiles/tf1).

I had a cluster (Azure Kubernetes Service/AKS Cluster) with the following nodes:

```
4x Standard_DS2_V2 nodes
8x Standard_NC6 nodes
```

In Azure, [NC6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/nc-series) nodes are GPU nodes backed by a single K80 GPU each, while [DS2_V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/dv2-dsv2-series#dsv2-series) are typical CPU nodes.

I used [TFJob](https://github.com/kubeflow/tf-operator) to configure my job with the following replica settings:

```
Master (limit: 1 GPU) 1 replica
Worker (limit: 1 GPU) 7 replicas
Parameter Server (limit: 1 CPU) 3 replicas
```

Here's my conundrum: The job fails as one of the workers throw the following error:

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:175] Check failed: err == cudaSuccess || err == cudaErrorInvalidValue Unexpected CUDA error: out of memory
```

I randomly tried reducing the number of workers, and surprisingly, the job worked. It worked only if I had *3 or less Worker replicas*. **Although it took a lot of time (bit more than a day), the model could finish training successfully with 1 Master and 3 Workers**.

This was a bit vexing as I could only use up to 4 GPUs even though the cluster had 8 GPUs allocated. I ran another test: When my cluster had 3 GPU nodes, I could only successfully run the job with 1 Master and 1 Worker! Seems like I can't fully utilize the GPUs for some reason.

Finally, I ran into another problem. The above runs were done with a very small amount of data (about 150 Mb) since they were tests. I ran a proper job later with a lot more data (about 12 GiB). Even though the cluster had 8 GPU nodes, it could only successfully do the job when there was 1 Master and 1 Worker.

Increasing the Worker replica count to more than 1 immediately caused the same cuda error as above.

I'm not sure if this is an Object Detection API based issue, or if it is caused by Kubeflow/TFJob or even if it's something Azure specific. I've opened a similar issue on the Kubeflow page, but I'm also now seeing if I can get some guide from the Object Detection API community. If you need any further details (like the tfjob yaml, or pipeline.config for the training) or have any questions, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. : (

Comment: Seems like perhaps you're nvidia device plugin is not installed or working correctly?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/gpu-cluster

Comment: @jpalma I did install the device plugin though, exactly following this same link

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the batch size used by the API.
Try to control the batch size, maybe as described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55529875/2109287

Comment: All examples I've run used a batch size of 1 though. That's the lowest possible.

Comment: where do you set the batch size?, Also my other guess would be that other workload on the GPU may be causing the issue. If it is not much trouble for you try to run on Standard_NC12 instead. because Standard_NC6 shares the physical GPU with other VMs

Answer (score 0):

this is because of insufficient gpu memory:
try this below commands
hope it'll help

```
$ sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*

$ sudo kill -9 pid_no (Ex: 12345)

$ nvidia-smi --gpu-reset
```

:)